# почему float убирает цветовой фон?

Tags: css, css3

В общем вот код, красный фон присутствует

```css
.main{
  width: 1100px;
background:red;

}
.first{
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
   background:lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  
  <div class="first">
  first 
  </div>
</div>
```

Но если добавить в класс first свойство float:left или right красный фон пропадает, почему так происходит?

```css
.main{
  width: 1100px;
background:red;

}
.first{
  float:left;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
   background:lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  
  <div class="first">
  first 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А вы знаете что делает float?

Comment: Вот и выросло поколение не верставшее на флоатах 

Comment: При заданом свойстве `float: left || right;`, элементы убираются из обычного "потока" и не растягивают родительские элементы по высоте. Если проинспектировать элемент `.main`, то вы увидите, что его высота == 0. Добавьте `.main::after {content: '';  display: block; clear: both;}`

Comment: P.S. Вспомнил еще один хак. Родительскому добавить `overflow: auto;`. (_эх, этим вопросом вернули меня минимум на лет 10 назад_ :) )

Comment: @Deonis спасибо большое, да, я действительно на флотах не верстал, нужно ли этот пробел заполнять или с приходом flexbox и новых технологий не советуете? И если всё же стоит, скажите пожалуйста эта статья подойдёт для 90 процентов ответов на мои вопросах о флотах? https://webref.ru/layout/learn-html-css/positioning-content

Comment: @РусланКамов, иметь представление о том, как работают даже те свойства, которые сегодня используются крайне редко, я считаю, что не помешает. Но заострять на них внимание - не имеет смысла. Да, той статьи вполне достаточно.

Comment: @Deonis просто хочется как можно скорее верстать начать для фриланса, сегодня весь день мучался с vertical-align . Надеюсь эта статья поможет https://web-standards.ru/articles/vertical-align/ спасибо Вам огромное.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main{
  width: 1100px;
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
}
.first{
  float:left;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  background:lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  
  <div class="first">
  first 
  </div>
</div>
```